# How to parse XML with prefixes?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<object-stream>
  <manhattan:state id="1" turn="0" start="red" current="red" type="select">
    <red id="2" displayName="Spieler 1" points="0">
      <segment id="3" size="1" usable="0" retained="11"/>
      <segment id="4" size="2" usable="0" retained="6"/>
      <segment id="5" size="3" usable="0" retained="4"/>
      <segment id="6" size="4" usable="0" retained="3"/>
      <card id="7" slot="0"/>
      <card id="8" slot="2"/>
      <card id="9" slot="3"/>
      <card id="10" slot="3"/>
    </red>
    <blue id="11" displayName="Spieler 2" points="0">
      <segment id="12" size="1" usable="0" retained="11"/>
      <segment id="13" size="2" usable="0" retained="6"/>
      <segment id="14" size="3" usable="0" retained="4"/>
      <segment id="15" size="4" usable="0" retained="3"/>
      <card id="16" slot="3"/>
      <card id="17" slot="4"/>
      <card id="18" slot="4"/>
      <card id="19" slot="4"/>
    </blue>
  </manhattan:state>
  [...]
</object-stream>
```

I want a simple DOM representation or so of it, but when I try to parse it with a `org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder`, it fails:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 2:
The prefix "manhattan" for element "manhattan:state" is not bound.
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:533)
        [...]
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: That's currently not valid XML. You need something like `xmlns:manhattan="http://..."`. Any reason you haven't got that?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Well... another program by a third party writes this .xml file, and I have to parse it somehow.

Comment: Well, in that case, from the stream tag, you can use DOM API to copy the node and create it as document and work with that document.

Comment: @Phani I don't understand, I haven't worked with XML in Java before...

Comment: @thejh: At this point the *first* thing I would do is notify the third-party that it's not creating valid XML documents. Getting them to fix the generator to create valid XML may well be the simplest fix - and it would certainly be the *best* fix.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you - you've got my upvote, and I know you're right, and I told them now, but at the moment, I just want this stuff to work quickly.

Comment: @JonSkeet: its actually valid and well-formed according to the xml spec, its just not namespace well-formed (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#Conformance)

Comment: @JörnHorstmann: Thanks for the clarification. I'm definitely using the word "valid" too loosely. I stand behind the *gist* of what I'm saying (make them fix the builder) but I appreciate your correction on the detail.

Comment: Grnaaah. I just built my own XML parser. Took a few hours and it will blow up if the input changes a bit, but it works for now. :/

Answer (score 2):

When you create a `SAXBuilder`, use `new SAXBuilder(false)` to disable validation.

Set `http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces` property to false to disable the namespace replacement thingy.

Comment: Adding that "no validation" parameter doesn't fix it, and that link gives me a 404.

Comment: @thejh: It's not a link, it's a *property* name.

Comment: Uh... how would I use that? Prepend it to the data stream somehow? Set it somewhere on the parser? I guess I still don't get it.

Comment: `parser.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);`
`parser.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefix", false);`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that tomorrow. :)

Comment: You meant `http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes`, right? Well, it's a different error now: `IllegalNameException: Namespace URIs must be non-null and non-empty Strings`

Answer (score 1):

Your input XML is well formed but not a valid XML document. So, first you need to make it a valid document for the parsers to parse properly. See if you could get the document stream and create a new Document without a namespace or prefix and your parsing should work.

Comment: Like, run a regular expression on the XML before parsing it? :D

Comment: No, copy the node and create it as document. Using regular expressions is the last option if possible get the copy of node and work with it.

Comment: Please go through the link for copying the nodes, unless if you can't control the validity of the document.
http://sevalapsha.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/copy-nodes-xml-documents-java-dom/

Comment: Doesn't that work only when the Document was already created? I don't get that far.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the error, use `xmlns` for the parent tag `object-stream`.

```
<object-stream xmlns:manhattan="http://....something">
```